# Can I get access to EditText setText method while using custom keyboard?

Tags: android, android-keypad

I am using a [custom keyboard](https://github.com/rkkr/simple-keyboard). My requirement is when user type some shortcut (like gm) then automatically (good morning) should  be there. I don't know how to do it with custom keyboard, because, in normal Editext we can just use TextWatcher and editext.setText("something"). Please help..

Comment: but you add TextWatcher to EditText, why custom keyboard make any problems?

Comment: @AlexRmcf I am not using textwatcher, the problem is about custom keyboard that I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are creating a custom keyboard then on commitTyped method in Softkeyboard class that are extended by InputMethodService.This method help to write any text on edit text. And another method in this class is OnKey, In this method, you should receive primary code 32. Basically, 32 code is the space key code in the soft keyboard. when you receive 32 code you get text from edit text and replace to another text through commitType method.
I think the shortcut character of the spelling you should store in Share preference and SQLite etc because sometimes the internet is not available on mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for help but there is no `commitTyped` method in whole project.

Comment: can you find the method where you write the text in edit text

Comment: There is no access to EditText, because keyboard is mine, but not Editext owner app.

Comment: I know the keyboard is custom if you are no access to edit text so tell me that what's doing your keyboard work. see your Inputservicemethod class if you don't understand your own code then attach the code of the input method class I will see and tell you.

Comment: I have used this code, please check - https://github.com/rkkr/simple-keyboard

Comment: I tried to search in InputServiceMethod class, but failed to get a solution.

Comment: I can see and tell you later

Comment: I see your code, you can write any text in the onStartInputView() method. In this method write this code:

getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(" " + "your_text" + " ", 1);

Comment: not important to write this code in onStartInputView() you write this code depending upon your scenario. this code is run  when the keyboard is open

Comment: One more thing.. How to get text of EditText? inside that class..

Comment: you can get the text in onpresskey() method

Comment: I mean, how to get complete text in EditText currently?

Comment: Also in this code where all event codes are written, I need to check all codes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229434/discussion-between-khemraj-and-muhammad-asad).